What does "cut it short in righteousness" mean in Romans 9:28?
Romans 9:28 NKJV

"For He will finish the work and cut it short in righteousness, Because  the LORD will make a short work upon the earth." [My emphasis].

Will God cut the work short, or,"cut short" people's expectation of a "long work"?
If cutting short is doing something in less time than is expected, what is the expectation that is cut short?
In this verse:
What will be cut short?
How will it be cut short?
When will it be cut short?

Consulting Young's Literal Translation, there seems to be some significance attached to tense, and also to who the prophecy initially spoke of. Taking it from verse 27, the start of the sentence, to the end of it:

"And Isaiah doth cry concerning Israel, 'If the number of the sons of
Israel may be as the sand of the sea, the remnant shall be saved: for
a matter He is finishing, and is cutting short in righteousness,
because a matter cut short will the Lord do upon the land, and
according as Isaiah saith before, 'Except the Lord of Sabaoth did
leave to us a seed, as Sodom we had become, and as Gomorrah we had
been made like'." Rom. 9:27-29 YLT

Isaiah spoke of a matter the Lord was in process of finishing, regarding the earthly nation of Israel. It was to prevent the nation ending up as Sodom and Gomorrah. He was acting in that nation, with its numbers as the sand of the sea, to save a remnant by "cutting short in righteousness."
The way Paul applies those quotations to what was happening in his day gives the full meaning. He shows at the start of chapter 9 of Romans that his people (Israel according to the flesh) had in Isaac "a seed" called by God. But the true Israelites were not children of the flesh, but the children of promise, and Gentiles also comprised this spiritual group who God would save by "cutting short in righteousness".  Paul also quotes from Hosea to show that those who once were not God's people, would become God's people - "sons of the living God" : A spiritual nation.
This is the ongoing work of "cutting short" in order to save a remnant, chosen of God, flowing from the physical to the spiritual.
The earth is to experience this great work of God; not just a tiny part of it, where one small nation lived, but Gentile nations also. That work was begun in the days of the old testament prophets, beginning with saving the nation of Israel. It was not obliterated, despite various attempts over the centuries.
Then came the promised Messiah, "who shall save his people from their sins" (Matthew 1:21), and the nation of Israel was given the initial privilege of being saved by Christ. Some were. His great work seemed to be cut short, but it then exploded globally. Thus the privilege was opened up to Gentiles and many more were saved. Yet still, the combined numbers of saved souls could only ever be called "a remnant" compared with the nation of Israel and earth's teeming billions.
This work continues to this day, but it will come to a sudden stop when all whom God will save have become part of the ecclesia, the gates of hell unable to overcome those called-out ones. All of this demonstrates God's righteousness, so that when the time comes to finish God's work of salvation in the earth, it will suddenly appear to have been cut short, but God's righteousness will have been incontrovertably proven by then. God's perfect timing means it will be stopped at exactly the right time. Yet Jesus did warn us that it would have to be cut short for the sake of the elect - the called-out ones. God must needs call an end to the tribulation they will increasingly suffer just before Christ returns:

"For then shall be great tribulation, such as was not since the
beginning of the world to this time, no, nor ever shall be. And except
those days should be shortened, [cut short] there should no flesh be
saved; but for the elect's sake those days shall be shortened."
Matthew 24:21-22 A.V.

1) What will be cut short? This on-going matter of God's saving grace.
2) How will it be cut short? By God ending the Day of Salvation and starting the Day of Wrath.
3) When will it be cut short? Once God decides all the elect have been gathered in.

The context clarifies the question.

“Though the number of the children of Israel be as the sand of the
sea, The remnant will be saved. 28 For He will finish the work and cut
it short in righteousness, Because the Lord will make a short work
upon the earth.”

However, the NKJV translation does not capture the sense of the OT text which Paul is referring to. Most interpreters deal with Paul's unusual wording here with such translations  as "decisively and quickly will the Lord execute sentence upon the earth."  The passage in Romans is a paraphrase of Isaiah 10:

20 And it shall come to pass in that day That the remnant of Israel,
And such as have escaped of the house of Jacob, Will never again
depend on him who defeated them, But will depend on the Lord, the Holy
One of Israel, in truth. 21 The remnant will return, the remnant of
Jacob, To the Mighty God. 22 For though your people, O Israel, be as
the sand of the sea, A remnant of them will return; The destruction
decreed shall overflow with righteousness. 23 For the Lord God of
hosts Will make a determined end In the midst of all the land. 24 Therefore thus says the Lord God of hosts: “O My people, who dwell in Zion, do not be afraid of the Assyrian. He shall strike you with a rod and lift up his staff against you, in the manner of Egypt. 25 For just a brief moment more, and my wrath shall be over, and my anger shall be set for their destruction.

Here, Assyria punishes Israel, but the Lord promises to suddenly save his people and destroy the enemy, as he did with Egypt in the time of Moses. This is apparently a reference to the miraculous salvation of Jerusalem during the time of Hezekiah, in which Isaiah was directly involved. (2 Kings 19) The remnant are those who had not been taken captive by the earlier Assyrian invasion of northern Israel or killed/captured after Sennacherib conquered every city in Judah except Jerusalem. They were saved by the sudden withdrawal of the Assyrian army from Jerusalem's walls due to a plague which killed many thousands of the invading soldiers.
In Paul's case, Isaiah's prophecy is used to demonstrate God's absolute sovereignty and power, in keeping with the opening of the chapter:

Is there unrighteousness with God? Certainly not! 15 For He says to
Moses, “I will have mercy on whomever I will have mercy, and I will
have compassion on whomever I will have compassion.” 16 So then it is
not of him who wills, nor of him who runs, but of God who shows mercy.
17 For the Scripture says to the Pharaoh, “For this very purpose I
have raised you up, that I may show My power in you, and that My name
may be declared in all the earth.” 18 Therefore He has mercy on whom
He wills, and whom He wills He hardens.

Conclusion: Paul paraphrases Isaiah 10. In that prophecy, it is the Assyrian invasion that will be cut short and a remnant is saved by a miraculous plague sent by the angel of the Lord during the reign of Hezekiah.  In Paul's case, the quote is used more generally, to demonstrate God's power and sovereignty, as that of a potter over his clay.

I have updated my answer to emphasize a problem with the NKJV that affects the OPs question: "What will be cut short?" I originally wrote that this refers to God's suddenly effecting the salvation of the remnant. On second thought I think the text deals with God's sudden execution of justice on the Assyrian army, which resulted in the deliverance of Jerusalem and Judah.

Thanks. [You say "Assyria is punishes"]  The  Isaiah 10 picture then is a  foreshadowing of Matt 24:22?

I meant to say "Assyria punished" God's people, but God would soon deal with them. Matthew often reads Isaiah as applying to the time of Jesus or even the very distant future. But this particular prophecy involved something that happened in Isaiah own lifetime. Indeed he was directly involved in it as Hezekiah's advisor. I'm not sure whether Matthew  (or Jesus in Matthew) understands this prophecy as apocalyptic or not.

Israel's final prophetic seven years (Daniel 9:27) will be the "cut short" work (the tribulation).  The fact that it is seven years long, and not drawn out any longer, is what makes it "short" (Matt 24:21-22).
'Righteous' will be that work of God (Rev 19:2), as those who experience this wrath will be well-deserving of it.
Specifically, the work will be complete after the results of the pouring out of the seventh and final bowl judgement upon the earth.
Revelation 16:17

And the seventh angel poured out his vial into the air; and there came a great voice out of the temple of heaven, from the throne, saying, It is done.

Christ will then physically return to earth at the end of this period to usher in Israel's promised and long awaited kingdom of heaven with Christ's millennial reign of it (Acts 1:6-11, Heb 8:10, Rev 20:4).
